# how to enable linter pylint enable in vs code when Python: Select linter>>pylint

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint, linter

I am not able to enable pylint in VS code from python:select linter  the dialogue box to enable linter doesn't appear  what to do? can someone help me ?

Comment: Did you restart VSCode?

Comment: I reinstalled it  then also it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Ctrl+,</kbd>

It will open up vscode settings, there you can search for "Pylint enabled" and tick the checkbox to enable it.

[image: Pylint enabled checkbox]

Note: if pylint is not installed, it will ask if it can install it. Allow that.

Comment: nothing happened when i open up the settings and then searched for Pylint enabled it displayed ''no settings found'' and  it also not  asked me to install it. please help .

Comment: Added an image to the post for clarification.

Comment: done it thank you but it don't show me errors that what i made ? now what to do to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

For using Python's code analysis tool "Pylint" in VS Code, please refer to the following:

1.Please install "pylint" in the python environment currently used by VS Code.(`pip install pylint`)

(Please note that the python used in the VS Code terminal is the same as the one displayed in the lower left corner of VS Code. check python: "`python --version`" )

2.Then use the following settings in "[settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)":

```
"python.linting.enabled": true,
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
```

[image]

Reference: [Linting Python in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting).